# Is ‘a clip of’ (X % growth) an idiom, or just a set of words?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I came across the phrase, ‘a clip of’ in the following line of the article titled ‘A Man in Shadow’ appearing in Time magazine (July 16).

> In a capital full of bluster and backroom deals, the quiet economist has long been admired for his （Manmohan Singh）restraint and personal integrity, characteristics that played a large part in his being handpicked by Congress Party leader Sonia Gandhi for the nation's top job in 2004. During his first term, India's *economy reached a clip of 9.6% growth.*

As I first thought ‘*a clip of’* (9.6% growth) is an idiom meaning ‘as fast (high) as,’ I consulted with Cambridge, Oxford, and Merriam-Webster online English dictionary, none of which carries “a clip of” as an idiom.

Then I searched Google, in which I found the following examples of the usage of ‘*a clip of*,’:‘

- A Clip Of Reality — YouTube
- This is a clip of our article for MTV. The writer Beverly Bryan did such a wonderful job of writing about Morning MUSUKO. — morningmusuko.tumblr.com
- Here is a clip of the performance we did 2 days ago for the opening of much music video awards in Toronto!! Campaigning — iamhok.tumblr.com

However, none of these examples seems to be relevant to ‘a clip of’ (X % growth) composition in the above article.

It seems to me “clip” in the above article simply means “speed, “ or “pace.” But I’m yet not sure of whether ‘a clip of (X% growth)’ is an idiom, or a mere set of words. Which would it be?

Does ‘clip’ here mean ‘speed’ as Readers English Japanese dictionary at hand renders the meaning of ‘clip’ as (collocual) 1.hit. 2.*speed, velocity*. 3.one time, once.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the context you provide, the words *fast pace* could be used in place of *clip*.

> During his first term, India's economy reached a *fast pace* of 9.6% growth.

I can see how this would be a difficult one to figure out from the dictionary.  NOAD has two entries for clip, with several diverse meanings listed.  In the *Time* article, *clip* is being used as a noun, in the sense of Meaning 3:

[image]

To answer your question directly: no, it's not being used as an idiom, it's just a set of words.

Incidentally, in your other cited examples (i.e., *a Clip of Reality* (from YouTube) or *a clip of the performance*), that would be an example of the first bullet under Meaning #1, referring to a *video clip*, (or, in the latter case, perhaps an *audio clip*).

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Comment: [McGraw-Hill's Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs](http://tinyurl.com/clipidiom) considers _at a fast clip_ to be an idiom.

Answer (score -1):

"a clip of" is technically correct. It's an antiquated form of British English, though, so you wouldn't use it frequently today.

Comment: Hi, welcome to English Language and Usage. Please improve this post by adding citations or explanations.

Comment: It's neither antiquated nor exclusively British, and [doesn't seem to be declining in use](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=at+a+clip+of&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3).